# Add radiobutton to hook_form

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules, drupal-views

I want to add radiobuttons to my module. How can I add using Add radiobutton to hook_form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function mymodule_some_form($form_state) {
  $form['radio'] = array(
    '#type' => 'radios',
    '#title' => 'Title',
    '#options' => array(0 => 'First', 1 => 'Second', 3 => 'Third'),
    '#attributes' => array('style' => 'display:inline-block;')
  );

  $form['select'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => 'Title',
    '#options' => array(0 => 'First', 1 => 'Second', 3 => 'Third'),
    '#attributes' => array('style' => 'display:inline-block;')
  );
}
```

See the [Drupal FAPI Documentation](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/6) for more information.

Comment: now i want a selectbox near to each radiobutton.in one row there must be a radiobutton and a select box

Comment: Its the same idea, look at the link Clive posted to see how to add the select

Comment: that i checked.. but i want both radiobutton and selectbox in single line. Now select box is showing after all the radio buttons. i have to attach selectbox to each radiobutton

Comment: @user966881: You can do this with CSS, I've updated the answer above...note the `'#attributes' => array('style' => 'display:inline-block;')` line